# Get list of DataField in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Is there anyway to get list of all DataField being bound in grid view.

Provide more Details,

Using Stadard GridView with object data source.

Comment: This topic can answer in both c# and vb, in case it may be looping through Gridview column.

Comment: If you means that vb and vb.net is difference, i changed it to vb.net

Comment: Could you please provide some more detail to your problem: like code and what type of datasource you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will build a delimited string of DataFields (field names) of just the bound fields in a GridView.  It does not include template fields, button fields, ...

```
String boundFields = String.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < grd.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    DataControlField field = grd.Columns[i];
    BoundField bfield = field as BoundField;

    if (bfield != null)
        boundFields += bfield.DataField + ",";
}
boundFields = boundFields.TrimEnd(',');
```

The following link also talks about finding the column index of a specific DataField and might be helpful: http://forums.asp.net/p/1076872/1584635.aspx

Comment: grd.Columns.Count returns 0 when AutoGenerateColumns is true. Any suggestion?

Comment: `protected void gvDispMsg_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)` that gives me the `HeaderText`. How can I get the `DataField` instead?